# Los eventos del gamepad de Uinput no funcionan

Tags: linux

¿Cómo están? Espero que puedan ayudarme con algo, tengo un problema desde Artix Linux, quiero conectar mi mando de Wii para usarlo como Gamepad, no quiere funcionar porque el módulo uinput no quiere interpretar los eventos asociados a Gamepad Inputs, no agarra por ejempo "BTN_A" ni los demás, pero si pongo otro como "KEY_A" si lo reconoce pero actúa como entrada de teclado en tal caso. ¿Qué solución me proponen?

Cabe destacar que uso WMinput, y ya tengo instalado cwiid, wminput, ya incluso fijé el módulo uinput en el kernel.